# Run .launch file with arg from .launch file

Tags: ros, rviz, roslaunch, openni.launch, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use a master .launch file to run another .launch file, but with an arg.

Specifically, I am attempting to create a .launch file which would be equivalent to running:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch camera:=openni
```

This is what I am currently attempting for my .launch file:

```
<launch>
  <!-- Defining the arguments -->
    <arg name="Kinect" value="1"/>

  <!-- Start the Kinect (openni_camera) -->
    <group if="$(arg Kinect)">
        <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch" arg="$camera:=openni" />
    </group>

</launch>
```

The .launch file runs correctly and openni.launch works fine, but it does not seem to be running the arg camera:=openni.  I can tell because I cannot view the tf topics in Rviz from openni_tracker.

I am currently using catkin in ROS Hydro with Ubuntu 12.04.  I appreciate your help.  Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199152/run-.launch-file-with-arg-from-.launch-file/) by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 323 on 2014-12-09

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hiro64](https://answers.ros.org/users/20213/hiro64/) on 2014-12-09**:
Can't you copy the openni launch file to your own folder and pass that argument inside it?

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2014-12-09**:
I am not quite sure what you mean by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are close, but what should work is the following small change to how you pass an argument tag inside of an include tag:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="Kinect" value="1"/>
  <group if="$(arg Kinect)">
    <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">
      <arg name="camera" value="openni"/>
    </include>
  </group>
</launch>
```

Also, you can use `true` instead of `1` in the value for your Kinect arg, and it is nice when you use `default` instead of `value`, like they did in `openni.launch`, since it makes it easier for launch files that include your launch file to modify the arguments.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2014-12-09**:
You are a life saver.  Thank you very much.  As you can probably tell, I am very new to this.

The source for this information can be found at [roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg) given by Dornhege below.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your syntax is completely wrong.
Check out the docs for correct examples:

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2014-12-09**:
Thanks.  Good to have the source.  Had I found that page, I wouldn't have asked the question.